# After upgrading, the Search module gives no results

Tags: 7, upgrading

I have upgraded a website from D6 -> D7 using Drush `site-upgrade` command. Using a bash script it takes a `drush archive-dump` of a D6 site, assures it's at the latest version of D6 and upgrades it to Drupal 7. After the upgrade I apply a new theme and configuration via the `Configuration` module.

After the upgrade if I do a re-index of Search I see the following output:

```
drush cron -v
Initialized Drupal 7.33 root directory at                              [notice]
/var/www/2014/comparative_literature/snapshot/dest_www
Initialized Drupal site comparative-literature at                      [notice]
sites/comparative-literature
Indexing node 1.                                                    [ok]
Indexing node 2.                                                    [ok]
Indexing node 3.                                                    [ok]
Indexing node 4.                                                    [ok]
Indexing node 5.                                                    [ok]
Indexing node 6.                                                    [ok]
Indexing node 7.                                                    [ok]
Indexing node 8.                                                    [ok]
Indexing node 9.                                                    [ok]
Undefined index: email email.module:109                                [notice]
Undefined index: email email.module:109                                [notice]
Undefined property: stdClass::$uri file.module:737                     [notice]
Undefined property: stdClass::$filemime file.module:775                [notice]
Undefined property: stdClass::$filemime file.module:819                [notice]
Undefined property: stdClass::$filemime file.module:862                [notice]
Undefined property: stdClass::$filemime file.module:834                [notice]
Undefined property: stdClass::$filemime file.module:834                [notice]
Undefined property: stdClass::$filemime file.module:834                [notice]
Undefined property: stdClass::$filemime file.module:834                [notice]
Undefined property: stdClass::$filemime file.module:744                [notice]
Undefined property: stdClass::$filesize file.module:744                [notice]
Undefined property: stdClass::$filename file.module:750                [notice]
Indexing node 15.                                                   [ok]
Undefined index: email email.module:109                                [notice]
Undefined index: email email.module:109                                [notice]
Undefined property: stdClass::$uri file.module:737                     [notice]
Undefined property: stdClass::$filemime file.module:775                [notice]
Undefined property: stdClass::$filemime file.module:819                [notice]
Undefined property: stdClass::$filemime file.module:862                [notice]
Undefined property: stdClass::$filemime file.module:834                [notice]
Undefined property: stdClass::$filemime file.module:834                [notice]
Undefined property: stdClass::$filemime file.module:834                [notice]
Undefined property: stdClass::$filemime file.module:834                [notice]
Undefined property: stdClass::$filemime file.module:744                [notice]
Undefined property: stdClass::$filesize file.module:744                [notice]
Undefined property: stdClass::$filename file.module:750                [notice]
Indexing node 16.                                                   [ok]
Indexing node 18.                                                   [ok]
Indexing node 19.                                                   [ok]
Indexing node 20.                                                   [ok]
Indexing node 21.                                                   [ok]
Indexing node 22.                                                   [ok]
Indexing node 23.                                                   [ok]
Indexing node 24.                                                   [ok]
Indexing node 25.                                                   [ok]
Indexing node 26.                                                   [ok]
WD cron: Cron run completed.                                           [notice]
Cron run successful.                                                [success]
Command dispatch complete                                              [notice]
```

This site is simple like 3 content types which are Basic Page, Faculty and News items. Pages index fine above, and the News and Faculty throw errors do to `file` (people headshots) and email field issues I guess ...

But, when I use the site to Edit a page or uplaod an image to the Faculty member it appears to work fine. **The search index is Built and content is in the tables but nothing ever returns from searching for say `academics` and its a keyword in the built index found in basic Drupal "Page" content type nodes.**

The search page sometimes spits out notices such as (related to file field issues, email field issues, etc):

```
Notice: Undefined index: email in email_field_formatter_view() (line 109 of /project/drupalwww/sites/mysite/modules/contrib/email/email.module).
Notice: Undefined index: email in email_field_formatter_view() (line 109 of /project/drupalwww/sites/mysite/modules/contrib/email/email.module).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$uri in theme_file_link() (line 737 of /project/drupalwww/modules/file/file.module).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$filemime in theme_file_icon() (line 775 of /project/drupalwww/modules/file/file.module).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$filemime in file_icon_path() (line 819 of /project/drupalwww/modules/file/file.module).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$filemime in file_icon_map() (line 862 of /project/drupalwww/modules/file/file.module).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$filemime in file_icon_path() (line 834 of /project/drupalwww/modules/file/file.module).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$filemime in file_icon_path() (line 834 of /project/drupalwww/modules/file/file.module).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$filemime in file_icon_path() (line 834 of /project/drupalwww/modules/file/file.module).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$filemime in file_icon_path() (line 834 of /project/drupalwww/modules/file/file.module).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$filemime in theme_file_link() (line 744 of /project/drupalwww/modules/file/file.module).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$filesize in theme_file_link() (line 744 of /project/drupalwww/modules/file/file.module).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$filename in theme_file_link() (line 750 of /project/drupalwww/modules/file/file.module).
Notice: Undefined index: text_processing in _text_sanitize() (line 319 of /project/drupalwww/modules/field/modules/text/text.module).
Notice: Undefined index: text_processing in _text_sanitize() (line 319 of /project/drupalwww/modules/field/modules/text/text.module).
```

So far as I can tell there are no Errors, only `Notices` during the upgrade process. Well there is 1 error from [Serial Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/serial) usage on the site -- but the project page says to ignore it. The CCK Migration shows all fields are migrated although an email and link field loose association with their original content type maybe?:
[image]

I'm so annoyed! I get alot of `Notices` but nothing is a fatal error, and the site is Editable as a logged in user so far as I can tell. But I'd love to fix search (and as a bonus get rid of the `Notices`) ...

Any pointers, thoughts, tips, prayers welcome. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I was kinda stupid and functions suck. Let me explain ...

At some point in my development of a D7 theme for my site upgrade I created a function:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_search_result(...) { ...}
```

to theme search results. It wasn't working right so I commented out it's body:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_search_result($vars) {
  #dpm($vars);
  #dpm($vars['info']);
  #unset($vars['info']);
}
```

But in my function above I'm missing a Pass-By-Reference operator on the `$vars` parameter. The proper function signature is:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_search_result(&$vars) { /* ... */ }
```

By merely commenting out the body of the function I left the function itself consume `$vars` and never return any `results` (due to the pass by reference operator missing) thus causing every search to say "No search results found" -- but not raise any errors.

Note:

- I saw my error after I used Xdebug and some targeted breakpoints to track the results in functionn `search_view` for example from a search form HTTP `POST`.
- I say functions suck because if this was an Object Oriented method then an IDE would be able to say the signature was erroneous; relying on `hook` functions created from macros I think is kinda silly.
- Maybe there were other ways to check this like examine the previous Git commit, but to me this type of bug is really really hard to track.